# JScript try catch network exception

Tags: javascript, exception, networking, try-catch, jscript

I'm writing a script that stores database backup files to multiple locations. In addition, the data is stored on a NAS, which is normally accessible. If this is not the case, the error message is to be intercepted.
I tried it this way:

```
wshshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

SetupPath = WScript.arguments(0);
if (fso.FileExists(SetupPath))
{
    //Load setup JSON
    SetupFile = fso.OpenTextFile(SetupPath, 1, true, 0);
    eval(SetupFile.ReadAll());

    // Parse setup configuration from JSON
    ...
    BackupPath = Setup["BackupPath"];
    FilesForBackup = Setup["FilesForBackup"];
    NASBackupPath = Setup["NASBackupPath"];
    ...

    CreateNewBackupFiles();

    Log("Script was successfully executed.");
}
else
{
    Log("Script was not successfully executed.");
}

/* Creates a new compressed database backup */
function CreateNewBackupFiles()
{
    tempfile = fso.GetTempName();

    file = fso.GetFile("C:\\Program\\7-Zip\\7z.exe");
    rarexe = file.ShortPath;

    script = rarexe + " a -r " + tempfile + " " + FilesForBackup;
    wshshell.Run(script, 0, true);

    fso.CopyFile(tempfile, BackupPath + PrefixBackupFile + "backup.7z");

    //Save to NAS
    if(NASBackupPath!="")
    {
            try
            {
                    fso.CopyFile(tempfile, NASBackupPath);
            }
            catch(err)
            {
                    Log("Path \"" + NASBackupPath + "\" not available.");
            }
    }
    fso.DeleteFile(tempfile, true); //delete tempfile
}

/* Saves a log in  "Debug.Log" */
function Log(msg)
{
    fs = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    a = fs.OpenTextFile("Debug.log", 8, true, 0);
    line = "[" + CurrentTime()+ "] ";
    line += "[" + WScript.ScriptName + "] ";
    line += "[" + msg + "]";
    a.WriteLine(line);  
}
```

Nevertheless, errors continue to be issued. I´m using the Script on Windows XP SP3. Is there a possibility to catch this error with javascript?

thanks

Comment: If this is the only code that ever generates errors, there's three reasons why this shall throw an error: `NASBackupPath` is not defined, there's a syntax error in your code or there is some other error with the `Log` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
NASBackupPath is defined at the beginning of the Script. If the Networkpath is available, everything works fine! The Log-function is also used to save other script information. So I think the try-catch statement doesn´t seem to be able to catch this kind of error.

Comment: Are you able to show the rest of the script or not?

Comment: I´m not allowed to show the whole script. I´ll sum it up and post the most important lines in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error. The error came from the "Log". First, not every time a new "File System object" must be created. It can be simply used the object "fso". In addition, the open text file must be closed at the end of the function. Here is the correction:

```
function Log(msg)
{
    a = fso.OpenTextFile("Debug.log", 8, true, 0);
    line = "[" + CurrentTime()+ "] ";
    line += "[" + WScript.ScriptName + "] ";
    line += "[" + msg + "]";
    a.WriteLine(line);  
    a.Close();
}
```